Camera is not detected after installing Ubuntu 24.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad T14 Gen 2 laptop
Previously I had used the integrated camera on my laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 without any problems.  After installing Ubuntu 24.04, none of the camera apps (including Cheese) is able to detect my laptop's camera.  I think the problem is a missing driver, but the driver is not identified on Lenovo's support web pages.  Is there another way to obtain the driver for Ubuntu 24.04?
$ robert@robert-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2i:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 17ef:6050 Lenovo Lenovo Precision USB Mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2c7c:0127 Quectel Wireless Solutions Co., Ltd. Quectel EM05-CE
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. Prometheus MIS Touch Fingerprint Reader
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

$ robert@robert-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2i:~$ dpkg -l *cam* | grep ii
ii  gstreamer1.0-libcamera:amd64 0.2.0-3fakesync1build6 amd64        complex camera support library (GStreamer plugin)
ii  libcamel-1.2-64t64:amd64     3.52.3-0ubuntu1        amd64        Evolution MIME message handling library
ii  libcamera0.2:amd64           0.2.0-3fakesync1build6 amd64        complex camera support library

